# Django model.delete() reseed primary key

Tags: python, django

Busy developing my Django app and as it goes I have test data that I would like to delete from some of my tables.

**How can I delete the entries and "reset" the primary keys so that the next time an element is inserted, it has `id=1`?**

When I run `.delete()` I am able to delete the row, but the primary key is not reset.

According to a bit of research this is standard with databases and I need to truncate the table.

Some suggestions are to Truncate the table with raw SQL code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('db.sqlite3')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE 'table'")
```

which does not seem to work and just gives the following error:

```
OperationalError: near "Truncate": syntax error
```

Other suggestions are to comment out the model and redo `migrate`. This is not an option either as there are multiple dependent foreign keys across the tables.

Is there no way to reset the primary key of a table?

Comment: Why do you need the IDs to start from 1 again anyway? If your code depends on this in any way you have a problem with your code.

Comment: Fair point. Suffering from a bit of OCD here and it wasted a good amount of time where, in the end as you say it is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(too long for comment)

1. surrogate keys are not supposed to be treated as dense, steady increasing enumerator - it's just a key, a surrogate - not real - key for building a database
2. dev db, test db, prod db should be separated
3. beware of demonstrating a surrogate key as it is: `invoices/3/` after making an order is clearly saying how popular a company really is.

When you do not test on prod, do not show ids to users, when your code does not rely on assumption that ids started with 1 and each next id=prior id+1, you stop thinking about how pure and beautiful actual id values are. For dev/test purposes - do whatever you want, even (as I said) drop the whole db. If this is a new project and you're preparing db for moving to prod - you might prefer running sql commands directly since this is one time job.

When running tests, Django by default creates and drops a new db.

To make preparation for testing easier there is a [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/) feature.

Answer (score 1):

It is unrelated to django, or at least not directly so. You need to reset the value of the sequence that generates the primary key, see https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html